# Is it permitted to hide sms and call notifications when my app is running?

Tags: ios, sms

Is it permitted to develop an app which is not inturrupted by incoming calls or sms? The idea is to hide the incoming call and sms notification when the app is running and to show the list of missed calls and sms when user close the app.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a question of being permitted or not. It simply can't be done. There is no (public) API that would let you even attempt such a feature.